# OpenLDAP: alock_recover failed

Tags: windows-10, openldap

I have followed the tutorial on zytrax.com to install Openldap for windows.
After successfully install I have imported users data from ldif file using `slapadd` command.

I was able to connect and retrieve users data using Apache Directory Studio.
After reboot my computer I am unable to start the stanalone openslap server.

When typing the command below:

```
C:\OpenLDAP>slapd -d 8 -h "ldaps://localhost:610/ ldap://localhost:389/" -f slapd.conf
```

I get the following error output:

```
C:\OpenLDAP>slapd -d 8 -h "ldaps://localhost:610/ ldap://localhost:389/" -f slapd.conf
62e67204 OpenLDAP 2.4.49 Standalone LDAP Server (slapd)bdb_db_open: database "dc=hamilton-medical,dc=com": unclean shutdown detected; attempting recovery.
62e67204 bdb_db_open: warning - no DB_CONFIG file found in directory ./data: (2).
Expect poor performance for suffix "dc=my-domain,dc=com".
62e67204 bdb_db_open: database "dc=my-domain,dc=com": alock_recover failed
```

I have find on google that I have to remove any file named `alock` file to fix the problem but I can't find such a file in my Openldap directory. Maybe I missed something during installation.

Is there anyone that can help me solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In `slapd.conf` you should have these two lines :

```
pidfile     /run/slapd.pid
argsfile    /run/slapd.args
```

You might have defined different paths in your config, but the idea is just to find these two files under your installation directory (eg. in `c:\openldap\var\run`), and delete them. Then the server should be able to restart.

@see https://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch4/win2k.html